# Use docker compose in Azure

Tags: azure-devops, docker-compose, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a pipeline running the following `docker-compose`-file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  # PostgreSQL Server
  projectservicedb:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=projectservice
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=projectservice
      - POSTGRES_DB=projectservice
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes: 
      - ./CreateSchema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/CreateSchema.sql    
    hostname: projectservicedb
    
  # projectservice running as WebService
  projectservice:
    image: myregistry.azurecr.io/projectservice
    depends_on:
      - projectservicedb
    ports:
      - 81:80
      - 442:443
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ProjectService/Dockerfile
      
volumes:
  projectservicedb:
    driver: local
```

So there's a service-image that depends on a db-image. My pipeline has two `DockerCompose@0`-steps: one for building the images and one for pushing them. Both use the above compose-file.

Now my question: how do I run an instance for that compose-file on Azure? Do I need two seperate container-instances or can I use a single one that contains both the images?

Currently I have an App-Service with a web-hook, so whenever a new image is pushed to my private registry for the `projectservice`-image, a new instance of the service is created. However for the DB there is no image within my registry, as it's just pulled from official repo. So I don't know how to access the DB from my App-Service.

Another approach is to use an App Service using the Docker-compose (preview)-feature.

However when I use the above docker-compose.yaml-file, I get the following error within the deployment-center:

> Exception in multi-container config parsing: YamlException: (Line: 16,
> Col: 9, Idx: 308) - (Line: 16, Col: 72, Idx: 371): Bind mount must
> start with ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to App Services (I noticed you also mentioned container instances (ACIs)), then note that docker-compose continues to be in a preview mode and some of it's features are not supported. In particular, the depends_on feature you are using above. The most reliable way is to establish that sequence programmatically.

You can deploy both or multiple images in a single App Service but only one can be exposed to the load balancer and thus to the public internet.

Comment: "You can deploy both or multiple images in a single App Service but only one can be exposed to the load balancer and thus to the public internet." Oh, cool, I suppose that's what I need to do. Didn't know that this is possible. And how do I achieve that?

Comment: You can go ahead and deploy your yaml on an App Service on the portal and select multi-container app (you will be asked to upload your compose file). Port 80 is the default. You can remove port 443 mapping along with the build steps (not supported as well). Id suggest simply publishing your Postgres and ProjectService images to ACR.  You might find these useful. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app and https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/docker_compose_depends_on.md

Comment: Isn't that exactly the still-in-preview-state-feature? Anyway I tried it using the steps mentioned in the docs, but on deployment-center there's an error: `"Exception in multi-container config parsing: YamlException: (Line: 16, Col: 9, Idx: 308) - (Line: 16, Col: 72, Idx: 371): Bind mount must start with ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}."`